# Efficient way of finding a description in a dictionary with synonyms

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, optimization, reduce

I have the following structure:

```js
const dictionary = [
  {
    words: ["foo", "bar"],
    desc: "This is a description"
  },
  {
    words: ["some", "word"],
    desc: "This is another description"
  }
]
```

I would like to access `desc` of a given word. For example:

`getDescription(dictionary, "some") // "This is another description"`

My initial implementation of `getDescription` looks like this:

```js
function getDescription(list, word) {
  return list.find(item => item.words.includes(word)).desc
}
```

This is a very easy way, but I was wondering if I can transform the `list` to something else to make it more efficient (in terms of speed), if say the `list` has 5000 items, where `words` vary from 1 to 5 or 6.

For example, would this initial transformation help?:

```js
list = list.reduce((acc, item) => ({
    ...acc,
    ...item.words.reduce((acc, word) => ({
      ...acc,
      [word]: item.desc
    }), {})
  }), {}
  )
}
```

It would duplicate a lot of the description, but accessing would be instant (`list["some"] // This is another description`).

Are these concerns at all? Would I feel any difference in speed with any perf. optimization, or is it just a waste of time?

Comment: What your asking sounds to me like a good place to use an in-browser db: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database#:~:text=Web%20SQL%20Database%20is%20a,Opera%2C%20and%20the%20Android%20Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Any preprocessing on `dictionary` would improve your performance. Converting it to an object would reduce the complexity from O(n) to O(1). That said, you should transform your dictionary by word into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), as they were created for that sort of thing. This is generally how an [inverted index](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inverted-index/) like Elasticsearch works.

```js
const dictionary = [
  {
    words: ["foo", "bar"],
    desc: "This is a description"
  },
  {
    words: ["some", "word"],
    desc: "This is another description"
  }
]

const { pipe, map, reduce } = rubico

const incrementMap = (m, [word, desc]) => {
  if (m.has(word)) {
    m.get(word).push(desc)
  } else {
    m.set(word, [desc])
  }
  return m
}

const flatten = arr => arr.flat(1)

// dictionary_arr => inverted_index
const createInvertedIndex = pipe([
  map(({ words, desc }) => map(
    word => [word, desc],
  )(words)),
  flatten,
  reduce(incrementMap, new Map()),
])

const maptionary = createInvertedIndex(dictionary)

console.log('maptionary.get(\'some\')', maptionary.get('some'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rubico/index.js"></script>
```

The above example uses my library, rubico. I recommend you take the [tour](https://tour.rubico.land/) to get a better grasp on what's going on.

Comment: I would prefer if I could solve this without any external library, I will check if your example is a good base for that.